# Autocomplete only for tab and enter

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

How could I disable autocompleting for this situation:

[image]
Pressing ( after `Rate` autocomplets with `DeviceRotationRate` as displayed:

[image]

I only want to use tab or/and enter for autocompleting, so I will know what to expect.

Comment: Take a look at this article https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense

Comment: Sorry, but I can't quite figure out which setting is for disabling this particular feature. All I could figure out was how to disable autocompleting at all, which is not what I'm looking for. I apologize again for my stupidity.

Comment: Could you please post your settings.json file with all of your custom settings? I tried messing around with my settings but I could not achieve the behavior you describe in your question.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. https://pastebin.com/TjizE29H. VS code (version 1.27)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The setting that turned this behavior off for me was:

`"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false`

You can find it in preferences - configuration - suggestions

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To accept `tab` but not accept `enter`, use:

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
```

as explained [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense).

Useful since you use enter in python to change line.

You can write that settings on `>Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` (using `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P` and fill `>Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`)