# Vscode autocompletes when typing a Bracket

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I Write code on a .js file (for example require).

When i get to the last character (r) vscode suggests "requestAnimationFrame":
[image]

Then if i press Shift and 9 (to add a opening bracket "(".) it auto completes to "requestAnimationFrame":

[image]

Why? And how can i stop it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to remove the auto-suggestions completely? You can press `Esc` to skip them once.

Comment: Thanks @telometto, but i want them to disappear if i don't press enter. is it how they suppose to work?

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280311/autocomplete-only-for-tab-and-enter solved a similar issue for me (add setting `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false`, found in preferences - configuration - suggestions)